# Can someone tell me how i make the MACH3 software to communicate with this board?

Tags: datasheet, wiring, board, cnc

[image]

I have a project to do in which I will need to use this board to move one of the axis of a machine.
But I can't find the datasheet for that board.
It serial number appears to be HW-3561224.

Besides, when I connect this card to the computer via USB, it does not make a sound indicating that it has found a device. There are no new drivers found. I've tested in a notebook with Windows 10, and another with Windows 7.

Can anyone help me with any relevant information about it?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The serial number is unlikely to be of any use. You need the part number. If you don't have a datasheet for it I suspect you will have a lot of grief. I'd say replace it with a board with good documentation and user support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USB port is only there to provide power for the 5V relay and buffers (maybe just the buffers, there appears to be a voltage regulator on the board as well). This is a so-called "breakout board"

The communication (such as it is) is via the large "Centronics" [parallel port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) just to the left of it. All the board does is to buffer and opto-isolate the signals from the parallel port lines to the stepper drivers, limit switch inputs and so on.

In order to get Mach3 to work well on a PC (providing properly spaced step/dir pulses in the tens of kHz range) you generally need a "real" parallel port, rather than a USB-parallel converter, so you'll have to find a plug-in board that has that kind of an interface. Notebook computers are generally unsuitable.

Photo from robotdigg.com

[image]

The "P" designations on the board refer to the pins on the DB-25 Centronics port. Note that some pins are logically inverted. It was originally a printer control port.

The designations can vary from that diagram, since much of it is configurable in Mach3. There's an excellent forum at the software supplier's website if you have a license.

Comment: Let me see if I got it. So the usb port is only for the relay?

Comment: I think it's for the buffers on the PC side as well.

Comment: I think now I understand. Thanks in advanced

Comment: P.S. there are actual USB controller boards, some of which work with Mach3, some require Mach4, they vary from cheap (with no support) to rather expensive (hundreds of dollars), with more powerful processors. Most are based on ARM microcontrollers, some with an additional FPGA. And, of course, professional CNC motion controllers are another order of magnitude more expensive than even those hobby ones.